# Entitlement Web Service Authentication

Tags: authentication, saml

I was tasked with implementing either a SAML authentication service, or a EWS (Entitlement Web Service Authentication) service, and I was wondering if anyone has any samples or documentation on such options. I am almost 100% sure that SAML is out of the question due to the time frame of the project.

EWS has been difficult to find online, I can't seem to find any good samples or documentation on implementing such service.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated which platform you are using, but there are open source SAML implementations that you can use. In php there is [SimpleSAMLphp](http://rnd.feide.no/simplesamlphp) and for java there's [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/).

Comment: Yes, my mistake... The site is already coded in ASP, with a MS SQL backend. The username and password is stored in the database table. I was looking into OpenSSO and Glassfish to implement an Identity Provider, however due to the timeframe of this project, I am trying to find the relevant information for EWS as oppose to having to install and configure the OpenSSO and Glassfish servers.